# Kernel and isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let n>1 be a natural number and let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be a real scalar. Let V be a subset and subspace of the vector space $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Define V as

$$ V=\{p\in P_n(\mathbb{R}):p(\alpha)=0\} $$
Let T be function linear transformation.

$$ T:P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}) ↦ P_n(\mathbb{R}),$$

$$p↦p*(X−α)$$

Show that the Ker(T) is the zero vector space and show that T induce a isomorphism between $P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $V$

To show that the Ker(T) is the zero vector space, I know that the I have to find the p, such that $T(p) = 0$. For the kernel would it be $Ker(T)=\{p \in P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})|T(p)=0\}$ this means $0=p(X-\alpha)=\{p|p*(X-\alpha)=0\} $ so $T(p) = 0$ when $X = \alpha $ right?

I am fairly uncertain how to prove that T induce a isomophism between $P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $V$. Hope somebody can verify or disprove the argument for the Ker(T) and help with the isomorphism part.

Comment: The range of $T$ appears to be $V$ and if the kernel is shown to be trivial then the first isomorphism theorem implies that $P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to the range, which is $V$.

Comment: you can directly show that the kernel is trivial or you can use the rank nullity theorem to show that the dimension of the kernel must be zero (the dimension of the range matches the dimension of the domain). In either case, you’d end up with a trivial kernel and the first isomorphism theorem finishes the rest.

Comment: The image of T would be: $p \in P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}), T(p)(\alpha) = p \dot (\alpha - \alpha) = 0$, which means that T is V. 
Then by the rank-nullity theorem $dim(Ker(T)) = dim(T) - dim(Im(T)) = 2 - 2 = 0$ ?

Comment: not quite. The dimension of the domain and range is not 2. Ponder that. But the rest works.

Comment: Would the $dim(T)-dim(Im(T)) = n - n = 0$ ? As $P_{n-1}$ is spanned by the elements $(1,x,x^{2} ... x^{n})$ or am I completely messing this up?

Comment: almost. 1. It is not $\dim(T)$. It would the dimension of the domain (real polynomials of degree less than or equal to n-1). 2. You’re close on the span - the last term should be $x^{n-1}.$

Comment: So it would be $dim(Ker(T)) = dim(P_{n-1}) - dim(Im(T))$ ? If so, then I do not understand how $dim(P_{n-1})$ can have the same dimension as $dim(Im(T))$ , since $dim(Im(T)) = P_{n})$

Comment: check the dimension of the image again. The dimension of the image can not exceed the dimension of the domain. To see this, consider mapping a basis in the domain. It will be a linearly independent set in the range in this case and so the size will not change.